# Laravel | Rellenar 2 tablas de MySQL a la vez

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, aplicación-web

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en Laravel, y tengo 3 tablas de MySQL: (**rol-usuarios-permisos_usuarios**), necesito saber como rellenar 2 tablas en un solo registró es decir el usuario se registra, se guarda un **id** como primario en la tabla "**usuarios**", y ese **id** es llave foránea de la tabla "**permisos_usuarios**", pero no se como rellenar la tabla "**permisos_usuarios**" con el **id** de la tabla "**usuario**", no se si me entendieron. Básicamente quiero rellenar 2 tablas en un solo registro, cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente si estas usando [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent)
 Hay una funcion para retornar el id creado en la insercion un ejemplo seria mas o menos esto

```
$empleados = new Empleados();
//aqui metes lo registros que estes guardando para tu tabla
$empleados->save();
$id = empleados->id;//este en el caso que tu llave primaria se llame id
```

para guardar en la otra tabla solo tendrías que usar la variable `$id` y ya con eso haces la otra inserción a la tabla privilegios

Comment: Muchas gracias Miguel, quedo genial la consulta, guarde el id en una variable y lo force a ser de tipo integer con settype y me funciono de maravilla!